# SQL select show table if not same value from another table (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is my query, I tried this query it works.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM conference_venue 
WHERE id_venue NOT IN (SELECT id_venue FROM submission_data WHERE id_submission = 1);
```

i want to display data in conference_venue. but I don't want to display data whose id_venue is the same as the submission_data table (same as id_venue whose id_submission is mentioned).

I'm trying to make a query for the laravel version, but it's a blank white screen with no errors.

```php
DB::table('conference_venue')
    ->whereNotIn('id_venue', function($q){
      $q->select('id_venue')
      ->from('submission_data')
      ->where('id_submission', '=', 1);
    })->select('*')->get();
```

This query works when I try it in sql query console but fails when I try it with Laravel query builder.

Comment: Have you debugged it? dd($query);

Comment: blank screen means, its returning NULL

Comment: make sure the query SHOULD return some data or the query is getting empty result

Comment: case : https://gist.github.com/rizkytegar/5ee2d19662cb6cfc654cbe06a6435bdb

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
DB::table('conference_venue')
     ->select('*')
     ->whereRaw(
     'conference_venue.id_venue NOT IN (SELECT submission_data.id_venue FROM submission_data WHERE id_submission = 1)'
     );
```

Or better yet, create a Model for `conference_venue` and `submission_data` (ie: `ConferenceVenue`, `SubmissionData`) and you can add Eloquent relationships for  `ConferenceVenue` and `SubmissionData`.

> Eloquent relationships, which supports a variety of common
> relationships (One To One, One To Many, Many To Many, etc.), are
> defined as methods on your Eloquent model classes. Since relationships
> also serve as powerful query builders, defining relationships as
> methods provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities.
>
> [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

On you `ConferenceVenue` Class, you can add a method something similar to the following:

```
public function available() {
     return this->hasMany(SubmissionData, 'id_venue')
          ->select('*') // You can also specify relevant columns ONLY
          ->whereRaw(
               'conference_venue.id_venue NOT IN (SELECT submission_data.id_venue FROM submission_data WHERE id_submission = 1)'
          );
}
```

Where you can use the relationship method as follows:

```
$available = ConferenceVenue::with('available')->get();
```